# xpath how can I select elements that have a number inside text?

Tags: xpath

```
<span>Постов: 223 / Файлов: 10</span>
<span>Постов: 23 / Файлов: 0</span>
<span>Постов: 63 / Файлов: 6</span>
```

How can I select all spans containing number <99 after "Постов: "

I tried this

```
//span[contains(text(), "Постов: ") and number(substring(text(), 9, 3))<99]
```

Answer (score 1):

The number you want appears after "Постов: " and before " /". So you can use `substring-after()` and `substring-before()`.

```
//span[substring-before(substring-after(text(),'Постов: '),' /') < 99]
```